# Achieve Hovering effect affects only some children divs, meanwhile hovering on not affected div cancels parent's hover effect

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to make the "cloth" text and icon to change its opacity as soon as the mouse is entering parent's div area. At the same time I want to cancel the effect once the mouse is over the "opt" button, and change its color to blue

This what I was able to achieve, but if I hover over the "opt" button, the text and icon above still have the opacity effect:

[image: preview]

```css
.options-btns:hover {
  background-color: #72b7f8;
}

#Cloth-Tool:hover #Cloth-Tool-img,
#Cloth-Tool:hover #Cloth-Tool-Text {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#cloth-option-btn:hover #Cloth-Tool-img,
#cloth-option-btn:hover #Cloth-Tool-Text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="runCloth()" id="Cloth-Tool" class="tools">
  <img class="toolIcons" id="Cloth-Tool-img" src="./images/cloth.svg">
  <p class="tools-text" id="Cloth-Tool-Text">Cloth</p>
  <button class="options-btns" id="cloth-option-btn">OPT</button>
</div>
```

I also what to be able to detect where user clicks: parent div(including cloth text and icon area) or on "opt" to be able run functions such as "runCloth()" or "openOptions()" later on JS side

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternate method to achieve the same output. By using JavaScript and adding an event listener on the option button in which you will add hover as the event listener apply your required properties within JavaScript they will overwrite your properties of CSS. I you still can not get me idea let me know I will write a code for it.

Comment: Js will overwrite the style for good so if I hover over the "opt" once, the style of the text and img will be changed and stay the same even if I leave the area, to fix this I need to add another event listener of mouse out and set all settings again, I don't what to do that so I would like to achieve my initial goal via CSS